# How come my textview does not create a line break when setting text, even when \n is used?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview, line-breaks, stringbuilder

I'm using the Kotlin language on Android Studio. I created a method where the contents of a txt file I saved get displayed in a textview.

```
textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString()).toString()
```

In this txt file, there are line breaks that have been created using \n when creating the file in the first place, but it does not appear when it's in the textview. When I look at the file itself, all the lines are formatted the way they should be, but never are in the textview. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you log output of `stringBuilder.toString()`? Do the newlines show in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You should use maxLines and minLines attributes in your XML, for example:

```
android:maxLines="6"
android:minLines="2"
```

EDIT :
just don't forget to set the maxLines bigger than the biggest posibility data.

Comment: yap i think that it will work, just don't forget to set the maxLines bigger than the biggest posibility data

Comment: of course, I'm gonna add this to my answer, thank you my friend.

Comment: @specialN9NE It does not appear to be working. Is there something else I should be trying?

Comment: @AbrahamKMS that's petty strange! Maybe something is wrong with your text file. you should check what data goes into textView so log the output of `stringBuilder.toString()` and make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me. I had set maxLines an minLines done. I tried to both use string builder and concentrated version in the project but neither of those created a new line and the text was going out of screen. The problem was I had:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText"
```

in my xml file. Apparently style can override other attributes you set like maxLine. The textview started to work with multiple lines when I removed the style attribute.